# Where is bootstrap.min.js.map ver 4.1.1 located?

Tags: angular, azure, web

I am having trouble running my angular static web app on azure server.

Generally my app is running OK until I get to the sending verification request from user's email back to my web app.

Whenever user is registering him/her self with my app (running on azure server), I send back to that user an email with the link (to my angular app ) to verify that user's e-mail.
When the user clicks on the email link to go to the page (angular component) for an account verification - Browser displays the following error:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.1.1/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I have checked that the `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.1.1/bootstrap.min.js.map` content does not exists, so the browser can' find it.

The question is why and what service is requesting that map file. My app is configured to use angular 5.2.2.

Has anybody experienced similar issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that the problem has nothing to do with bootstrap file.
I was using web.app for configuring URL rewrite.
Instead of web.config I had to use the staticwebapp.config.json with the following content:

```
{
"navigationFallback": {
"rewrite": "/index.html",
}
}
```

As simple as that.
However I don't know why I web.config is not working for rewrite on azure.
Maybe someone with the knowledge in this are could shed some light on that?
Regards